# HTML functions?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a repeated HTML code, like:

```
<figure class="print">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="images/5.png" alt="" />
        <dl>
            <dt>Client</dt>
            <dd>Envato</dd>
            <dt>Role</dt>
            <dd>Print</dd>
        </dl>
    </a>
</figure>
```

Is there a smart way to make a 'function' out of it (that accept the captions and image as parameters), or do I need to repeat that code so many times?

Comment: In HTML you dont have functions!!!

Comment: html is not a programming language, its just a style language. So you have to repeat the code as many times you need it.

Comment: ok - so maybe using javascript somehow for that? jquery?

Comment: You should use Javascript to do this

Comment: It usually makes sense to make the markup at the server side. Look-up php.

Comment: - how do use javascript for that?

Comment: You can use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) templates for example.

Comment: xslt is more like HTML than javascript is, as long as your input data is in XML...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using jquery template.

```
<script src="jquery.tmpl.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var data = [
{ name: "Astor", product: "astor", stocklevel: "10", price: 2.99},
{ name: "Daffodil", product: "daffodil", stocklevel: "12", price: 1.99},
{ name: "Rose", product: "rose", stocklevel: "2", price: 4.99},
{ name: "Peony", product: "peony", stocklevel: "0", price: 1.50},
{ name: "Primula", product: "primula", stocklevel: "1", price: 3.12},
{ name: "Snowdrop", product: "snowdrop", stocklevel: "15", price: 0.99},
];
$('#flowerTmpl').tmpl(data).appendTo('#row1');
});
</script>
<script id="flowerTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <div class="dcell">
  <img src="${product}.png"/>
  <label for="${product}">${name}:</label>
  <input name="${product}" data-price="${price}" data-stock="${stocklevel}"
  value="0" required />
 </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

with HTML you don't have the possibility to write functions that generate what you want. It seems that you would like to generate dynamic content. This is usually done by employing a scripting language.

So you have two options here:

1. Use a server side scripting language like PHP
2. If you want a client side solution you could use JavaScript which can dynamically create content for you.

For further information just Google for some simple tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

There are no way in pure HTML.

You can use JavaScript(jQuery) or back-end script, like PHP.

```
$("html").append($(".print").clone());
```

Answer (score 1):

As other people have said, HTML is a declarative language. However, with modern frameworks like [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/), you can write things like:

```
<figure class="print" ng-repeat="figure in figures">
    <a href="#">
        <img ng-src="{{figure.image}}" alt="" />
        <dl>
            <dt>Client</dt>
            <dd>{{figure.captions.client}}</dd>
            <dt>Role</dt>
            <dd>{{figure.captions.role}}</dd>
        </dl>
    </a>
</figure>
```

The corresponding model would be:

```
var figures = [{
  image: 'images/5.png',
  captions: {
    client: 'Envato',
    role: 'Print'
  }
}, {
  image: 'images/6.png',
  captions: {
    client: 'Another caption',
    role: 'Print'
  }
}];
```

It takes some time to get used to it, but you should read the code of their TODO example app.

Comment: This is the simplest way and even has one-to-one relation with his original html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#template) templates, for example:

```
<script src="http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>

<script id="template" type="text/html">
  <% data.forEach(function(item){ %>
    <figure class="print">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="<%= item.src %>" alt="" />
        <dl>
          <dt>Client</dt>
          <dd><%= item.client %></dd>
          <dt>Role</dt>
          <dd><%= item.role %></dd>
        </dl>
      </a>
    </figure>
  <% }); %>
</script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

In your JavaScript:

```
var data = [
  {
    src: 'images/5.png',
    client: 'Envato',
    role: 'Print'
  },
  {
    src: 'images/4.png',
    client: 'Foo',
    role: 'Bar'
  }
];

var template = document.querySelector('#template').innerHTML;
var html = _.template(template, {data: data});

document.querySelector('#container').innerHTML = html;
```