# creating dynamic div tag and place the data in that div tag, the data which is fetched from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I have created dynamic hyperlink and fetched data from database. now i need to put those data in particular div tag. Please help me.

```
 <div runat="server" id="bdy">

 </div>

Code Behind

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    MySqlCommand inscmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from category", con);
    MySqlDataAdapter a = new MySqlDataAdapter(inscmd);
    DataTable t = new DataTable();      
    foreach (DataRow row in t.Rows) 
    {
       bdy.InnerHtml.Equals("<a href=\"category.aspx?refid=" + row["cid"] + "\">" + row["catname"] + "</a><br />"); 

       // bdy is div name 
                 Response.Write("<a href=\"category.aspx?refid="+row["cid"]+"\">"+row["catname"]+"</a><br />");               

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the string builder class to add the items, like this:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataRow row in t.Rows) {
    stringBuilder.AppendFormat("<a href=\"category.aspx?refid=" + {0} + "\">" + {1} + "</a><br />", row["cid"], row["catname"]);
}
bdy.InnerHtml = stringBuilder.toString();
stringBuilder.Clear();
```

Comment: thanks Ramesh Sivaraman. but error is showing in stringBuilder.appendformat();

Error is:
Only assignment, call, increment,decrement, and new object exp can be used as a statement

Comment: sorry, ohh its just the place holder not set correctly.. stringBuilder.AppendFormat("<a href=category.aspx?refid= " +"{0}" + "/> {1} </a><br />", row["cid"], row["catname"] );

Comment: I changed little bit in this . now i got correct output. Thank yo so much Ramesh..

Answer (score 1):

You can get data from database , serialize it to Json format and send it to client by ajax.
Then you can use jquery template to create dynamic divs. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170239/html-functions/18170823#18170823), it could be helpful

Comment: is that not a double task? I thought he could easily manipulate the element and data using string builder and attaching it to the div.. I know your way he could save whole page post back and minimize the data transmitted.. would like to know if there is any other advantage of it??

Comment: No at all, you just get raw data, serialize it and send to view and at client side you can manipulate it by what I just suggested before. So there is no duplication by this way.

Comment: You'r right, I thought the OP is not looking for an Ajax solution.